C#.NET - Combine multiples .png in one Bitmap (.bmp)
I have multiples images.png (with names) stored on a folder.
From code (C#) I want to create a rectangle bitmap (with transparent background not white) where all the images are embeded.
Something like this:

How can I do this?

If you are using .NET Framework I would suggest taking a look at GDI+. It allows you to very easily draw shapes and other images without much work:
// Create an image of your desired size
var bitmap = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    // Load another image and draw it at a certain position
    var otherImage = Bitmap.FromFile(@"otherimage.png");
    g.DrawImage(otherImage, new Point(60, 10));
}

bitmap.Save(@"output.bmp");

EDIT: Seems I was wrong and you can now use GDI+ in .NET so you should not need the inefficient solution below.
If you are using .NET, you can still use Bitmap by referencing System.Drawing.Common, but you won't get GDI+. . This makes the manipulation a bit harder as you only have GetPixel/SetPixel by default. So basic copying is easy to implement but anything related to stretching, drawing lines etc. is going to be work. If you want to do this you should look for image manipulation libraries for .NET.
For the case you stated, it seems that simple copying is enough:
var bitmap = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
var otherImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"otherImage.png");
CopyTo(otherImage, bitmap, 60, 10);

void CopyTo(Bitmap source, Bitmap destination, int offsetX, int offsetY)
{
    for (var x = 0; x < source.Width; x++)
    for (var y = 0; y < source.Height; y++)
    {
        destination.SetPixel(x + offsetX, y + offsetY, source.GetPixel(x, y));
    }
}

bitmap.Save(@"output.bmp");

Either way, you need to do a bit of layouting to determine the right size of the final image and to position the images correctly but it should get you started.

Why do you use g.Save() without Restore, omitting the result, just before disposing the Graphics? Also, the 2nd example is both very inefficient, and also unnecessary. The 1st example works under the same conditions both on .NET and .NET Framework. When it doesn't work (eg. the terget bitmap has indexed or unsupported pixel format), then the 2nd example will also fail. "If you are using .NET, you can still use Bitmap [...], but you won't get GDI+" - this is simply not true. Starting with .NET 7 it works only with GDI+. With .NET 6 and below it can also use libgdiplus on Linux.

I am certainly no GDI expert but that seemed to do the trick, saving the changes to the Bitmap. 2nd example is very inefficent sure but does the trick. If you don't need the performance it gets the job done without going into LockBits territory. But then again if you need perf probably use a library for image manip

Graphics.Save does not save any visual changes but returns a GraphicsState containing the current clippings and other configuration that can be restored by a Graphics.Restore call. As for the performance part, I happen to have such a library. It actually has a few DrawInto overloads. But if the OP does not want to use 3rd party libraries, your 1st example would be just fine without the g.Save() part.
